# How to add project dependencies to specific platform targets created by the `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Previously, building multiplatform projects using Gradle relied on separate Gradle plugins per targeted platform: `kotlin-platform-common`, `kotlin-platform-js`, and `kotlin-platform-jvm`.

[Starting from Kotlin 1.3](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-1-3-m2-new-multiplatform-projects-model/9264), this is now unified using one `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin. [The current documentation specifies how to set up multiplatform projects using this approach](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#setting-up-a-multiplatform-project).

However, in my project I have multiple multiplatform projects with some dependencies between them. With the old multiplatform configuration, each different platform is a separate module and adding dependencies between projects required adding project references in each platform-specific module to corresponding modules in the other project: e.g., `project(':some-library:some-library-js')` to add a dependency to the JS module from within another JS module.

While migrating to the new multiplatform configuration, I now need to add a dependency from a project configured using the old configuration method to a project configured using the new `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin.

**Given that platform-specific modules are now specified and managed by the new plugin, how do I go about this?**

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain whether the following approach is the recommended method, or I overlooked any potential issues, but my projects compile and all tests pass.

In Gradle, you can add dependencies to specific project configurations:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':some-library', configuration: 'configName')
}
```

By trial and error I figured out that specifying the following configuration dependencies per platform module type works:

- common: `configuration: 'archives'`. Without this, Gradle configuration fails as code dependencies are not found.

Without the following, compilation fails:

- jvm: `configuration: 'jvmDefault'`
- js: `configuration: 'jsDefault'`

For example, for the JS module as specified in the question:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':some-library', configuration: 'jsDefault')
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment. Was trying to get my Android library to depend on the jvm artifact of my other multiplatform project for like a week. "jvmDefault" did the trick!

Comment: I think common should be 'default' instead of 'archives' based on https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client/issues/57#issuecomment-341329755

Comment: Also, this makes gradle work but intellij doesn't like this. I have a base library and an app that uses it. The app's common folder doesn't see classes from the library's common folder in intellij. I think due to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27801

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you don't need to specify the platform in project-to-project dependencies involving Kotlin Muiltiplatform projects. The Kotlin plugin sets up dependency resolution in a way that Gradle will choose the appropriate target's artifacts automatically.

So, for example, in a Kotlin/JVM single-target project, you can just use a `project("...")` dependency on a Multiplatform project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":multiplatform-library")
}
```

If `:multiplatform-library` has a JVM target, this dependency will get resolved to the JVM target's artifact. Otherwise, you will encounter a dependency resolution failure with candidate configurartions listed.

This is described in the Kotlin reference, [Building Multiplatform Projects with Gradle – Adding Dependencies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#adding-dependencies), but is applicable to single-platform projects, too:

> <...> a `project('...')` dependency on another multiplatform project is resolved to an appropriate target automatically. It is enough to specify a single `project('...')` dependency in a source set's dependencies, and the compilations that include the source set will receive a corresponding platform-specific artifact of that project, given that it has a compatible target.

If this does not happen for you, please post the specific dependency resolution failure log, or file an issue at https://kotl.in/issue.

Comment: When you say, _"The Kotlin plugin"_, do you mean `kotlin-multiplatform`? My question was, what if from a project using the old platform-specific plugins (e.g., `kotlin-platform-js`) you need to reference a project which is set up using `kotlin-multiplatform`? I understood that once fully upgraded to `kotlin-multiplatform` for all projects, what you mention works (and in fact, that is what I have now). But, in between, I wanted to be able to compile to see whether everything worked correctly, as not to have to upgrade all projects at once.

Comment: The `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin shares a lot of code with the single platform plugins, and yes, this dependency resolution setup should be valid for those plugins, too.

Comment: Just tried this by checking out an old version. Fails with _"Cannot choose between the following variants of project :multiplatform-library"_ ... followed by a long list of all variants (jsCompile, jsCompileOnly, jsDefault, jsRuntime, jsRuntimeElements, ...). Specifying the configuration variant manually [as in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280862/590790) does work.